# HQL persist fails to update record

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to implement the `classes` table so that the `classname` text field must be unique for each `termid`. The text field is not case sensitive (`utf8_general_ci`).

Portion of SQL script for MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE classes (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    classname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    classcode VARCHAR(20),
    termid INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,  
    CONSTRAINT fk_classes_term
        FOREIGN KEY (termid) REFERENCES terms (id)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT uc_classnames UNIQUE (termid, classname)
);
```

The repository layer is responsible for the update. I have tried it with and without exception handling.

```
public void updateClass(ClassEntity classEntity)
{
    entityManager.persist(classEntity);
    entityManager.flush();
}
```

I expect an exception to be thrown as soon as a conflict has been found, i.e. a `classname` changed so that it is the same as that used by an existing entity with the same `termid`.

I have been getting errors like this when I change just the case of a letter in `classname`.

> CreateEditClassForm.onSubmit failed with exception.
>   org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not
>   commit JPA transaction; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as
>   rollbackOnly

I am hoping to get something like a `javax.persistence.EntityExistsException`.

Is there something wrong with the SQL script or could it be with the database configuration?

The user interface is coded in Java Wicket and should not have to check the database when updating.

Edit: Added ClassService with one (of 23) method.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

// project imports omitted

@Service
@Transactional
public class ClassService
{
    @Autowired
    private ClassRepository classRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ClassUsersRepository classUsersRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TermRepository termRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TermService termService;

    public void updateClass(ClassEntity classEntity)
    {
        classRepository.updateClass(classEntity);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you mark your Service class method as `@Transactional` ?

Comment: Yes. 'ClassService' is marked '@Service' and '@Transactional'. 'ClassRepository' is marked '@Repository'.

Comment: can you please post your `ClassService` ?
`@Transactional` on service **method** signature only, not on the entire Service class.

Comment: Why should it be placed only on a method?